# What kind of bike do I have? Serial number is VF-8S3-20.5-9

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

BMX frame has two holes on front tube for forks.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you ever ask this question before stripping everything that could be used to identify the bike?

Comment: Serial numbers are useless unless you know the brand, AND that brand has some kind of structure to their numbering system.  Its not a VIN like a car has to have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a bike.  You have pieces of a bike, which is the frame and forks, crank, bottom bracket, chainring and pedals .  Needs a few more parts to be a complete bike

It looks moderately modern with three-piece crank, and a relatively small chainring.

The cranks have a pinch bolt holding them to the BB axle, but its much newer than a cottered crank.  No idea why the cranks are wrapped in masking tape - could be a half-finished paint job.

Certainly the frame has a half-arsed paint job that looks like it came from a rattlecan.  I notice there appears to be paint sprayed directly onto the bare brake mounting bosses for the rear wheel.

Also the forks look more like a MTB with the consistent tube size right down to the dropout.  This suggests to me that its less than 10 years old.

Can't see a lot in the head tube/headset area - look closely for decals or a head tube badge to help identify it.

---

Your comment about holes in the fork are probably breather holes from when it was welded.  There has to be somewhere to let hot gasses vent else a closed metal unit pops like a balloon, or it ends up sealed with a low pressure inside which is bad for strength and hidden rust.

To fix it up to rideable state you'll need to source all the missing parts, which are two complete wheels, tubes/tyres/rimtape, freewheel, chain, brakes for the back, some kind of brakes for the front, brake inner+outer cables, seat post, saddle, stem, handlebar, grips, and brake levers.  May require to add reflectors too depending on the road laws in your location.  All this is doable, but keeping costs reasonable means browsing ebay etc for a useful part.

One of the best tools for this work is a set of vernier calipers.